# Problem with ubuntu 10.10 running from USB drive

Tags: ubuntu, usb, installation

I recently downloaded Ubuntu 10.10 and created an USB drive with that. I started to run the Ubuntu from that USB drive. But I am facing so much problem. I am thinking why its not so much easy like Windows to do all my job in ubuntu. Always I get some error message or to install something. This time I am getting the following errors. I am trying to download and install Aircrack-ng. So used the command sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng. But the installation stops with the following error :

update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
cp: cannot stat `/vmlinuz': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing bcmwl-kernel-source (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 bcmwl-kernel-source
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I don't even have the aptitude command installed till now.

Are all these errors because of I am running the ubuntu from USB drive?

Is there any simple and easy way to go to Ubuntu Software Center and download all the required essentials at one shot and then Aircrack-ng? I could not find the Aircrack-ng in Ubuntu Software Center

Can anybody give me detail steps to solve all my problems above. I am frustrated searching for updates and installations. When something works and something does not work. Can anybody suggest me how I should proceed after installing ubuntu to run on a USB drive. So that I can use the OS like Windows. Like software download,wireless driver, sound, video, documents, C:, D: all things should be there. Please somebody help.

Comment: Are you sure it is 10.10, not 11.10? You mention the Software Centre which was introduced in 11.04, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you haven't installed ubuntu to your flash drive correctly... I recommend following the steps on Ubuntu's Website, as well as using a program like Unetbootin or my favorite UltraISO (google them)...

Now as far as some of the other things:
Ubuntu will never work like windows, it doesn't try to work like windows, and as far as the constant need for installing new packages goes, that will always be there as well. It's part of the idea, ubuntu is a fairly stripped down OS, It doesn't come with most of the parts one would expect from an operating system like windows, that said all of these things can be installed from various sources.

As far as traditional locations, like C:, they don't exist in ubuntu, the root or "/" is basically a rough concept of the same thing. As far as documents folders and such they can be found in your home directory "~" or you can click "Places" --> "Home" to find that.

Also one last note, quite a bit of great free software can be found in the ubuntu "universe" which can be found by going to "Applications" --> "Get new software"

Comment: I agree with that Windows and Linux are conceptually different and if you want to have something that does work exactly like Windows does, you should use Windows. But I disagree on your notion that Windows comes with more software pre-installed. And actually the package management is rather an advantage of Ubuntu over Windows than a disadvantage.

Comment: Oh, and the OP seems to use a recent version of Ubuntu, as he mentions the "Ubuntu Software Center". So universe is by default included in the software sources. And Unity is the standard desktop, so instead of 'Places/Home' it's the clicking the "Folder with a house" symbol in the Launcher on the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking several questions at once.

For the "installing everything I need", it depends on your needs. Maybe ask on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) with a description of what your requirements are (better still, which packages you installed so far) and it might be somebody points out some meta-package that contains most of the stuff you need.

For most standard users it's sufficient to install the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras`. It contains a lot of software that is not included in the standard install due to licensing etc. (Flash, various audio/video codecs etc.)

However if you want to play with aircrack-ng, I guess you probably do not qualify as standard user. While Ubuntu includes aircrack-ng, it needs quite a bit of installation/configuration to make it a good tool for (wireless) penetration testing.

For this purpose you are probably better off with a specialised distro like [BackTrack](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/). It also already includes the wireless drivers with support for packet injection built in and so on. It's single purpose (I would not use it as my normal system to work on everyday) but saves you some effort when used for that purpose.
It is designed to be installed on a DVD or USB stick.